# Android SDK unable to find 'android.bat' - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my first time making Android Apps. Using Eclipse for the to make the android apps, I get stuck constantly, when trying to open the SDK Manager, its Android Console says:

> Error 2: Unable to find 'android.bat'

However, to download the android plugin, you need to use the SDK Manager right?  That's were the problem happens, the SDK Manager worked before but not now?

My Operating system is Windows 8.1, 64-bit. Android SDK is 6.0 (api 23).

### Edit

I have also tried changing `android.bat` to explicitly show the path to the `java.exe` (I did this because, when researching this problem, a tech website said I should do this to fix the problem, however this did not fix it).

Comment: Eclipse has been deprecated for the majority of the entire year. It's almost 2017 - use Android Studio if you are just starting. Your computer should support it

Comment: Anyway, the Eclipse ADT plugin is independent of the SDK Manager.

Comment: @criket_007 you think it will run on a 2.16ghz laptop?

Comment: Maybe. Just try. If it does, you'll still have the same problems because the Android SDK is necessary to get running to develop at all. I'd suggest just downloading everything again.